# convert non digits in one column to nan in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My pandas data frame is as below. IN the "price" column, I want to convert non digit values to nan. Thanks.

Input:

```
ID, name, qty, price 
1, pen, 4, 55
2, book, 5, ai
3, PENCIL, 5, 100
4, book2, 10, si
```

output:

```
ID, name, qty, price 
1, pen, 4, 55
2, book, 5, nan
3, PENCIL, 5, 100
4, book2, 10, nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df['price'], errors='coerce')
```

If they're strings, use `mask` and `str.isnumeric`:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].mask(~df['price'].str.isnumeric())
```

`mask` automatically converts data that match the condition to `NaN`.

Or use `str.isaplha`:

```
df['price'] = df['price'].mask(df['price'].str.isalpha())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `str.replace` here:

```
df["price"] = df["price"].str.replace(r'^.*\D.*$', np.NaN)
```

The regex pattern `^.*\D.*$` will match any `price` entry having at least one non digit character, and will selectively replace with `nan`.